# Python selenium scrap website returns nothing

Tags: python, selenium

I have used the previous code to download some titles from the website, but somehow it began to return nothing, but no errors.

```
driver.get('http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='input-group-wrap form-control dropdown-btn']/input[1]")))
datefield_st.click()
s1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-left')
s1.send_keys("2022-3-7")
s2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-right')
s2.send_keys("2022-3-21")
driver.find_element_by_id("query-btn").click()
links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书' and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]]")))]
titles=[title.text for title in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left title-text multiline' and contains(text(), '募集说明书' and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]//parent::a")))]
dates=[date.text for date in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left title-text multiline' and contains(text(), '募集说明书' and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td")))]
print(link,title,date)
```

Comment: Did the website you're scraping update their html source?

Comment: I think not, the xpath is still the same

Comment: Cause this xpath does not exist anymore `//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书' and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]]`

Comment: When you say link what exactly you are trying to extract?

Comment: @cruisepandey Hi, I think it still has the xpath

Comment: @cruisepandey Why you said that xpath does not exist

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste the xpath and see if your desired element is getting highlighted with 1/1 matching node, it is not matching anything

Comment: I think you cannot just paste that xpath, instead ,you should search for ```//a[@attachformat]//span```, and it do exist

Comment: `I think you cannot just paste that xpath,` if the XPath does not exist Selenium will never find it. Also use @ to reply

Comment: Actually the results should be nothing cause it won't find anything on that page with those values. I tried it with values on that page and it will actually find values.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Hi, thanks! But I could see title contains the word'募集说明书‘ in the first page in date range, but it still return nothing

Comment: //a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书' ) and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]] gives me 5 elements?

Comment: This part in each of your xpaths were off.  contains(text(), '募集说明书' ->missing )

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Do you mean in the code I miss the part? But the code is ``` wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书' and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]]")))]```, I think it contains this part, still no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.get('http://www.szse.cn/disclosure/bond/notice/index.html')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='input-group-wrap form-control dropdown-btn']/input[1]")))
datefield_st.click()
s1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-left')
s1.send_keys("2022-3-7")
s2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-right')
s2.send_keys("2022-3-21")
driver.find_element_by_id("query-btn").click()
links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书') and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]]")))]
titles=[title.text for title in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left title-text multiline' and contains(text(), '募集说明书') and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]//parent::a")))]
dates=[date.text for date in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left title-text multiline' and contains(text(), '募集说明书') and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td")))]
print(links,titles,dates)
links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@attachformat][.//span[contains(text(),'募集说明书') and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]]")))]
titles=[title.text for title in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left title-text multiline' and contains(text(), '募集说明书') and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]//parent::a")))]
dates=[date.text for date in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='pull-left title-text multiline' and contains(text(), '募集说明书') and not(contains(text(),'摘要'))]//ancestor::td//following-sibling::td")))]
print(links,titles,dates)
```

Missing )'s and wrong variable names for the print.

Comment: OH! thank you ! I have not recognized that the ')' is missing lol, I have not changed the code, no ides how this happens, thank you !